# create a mysql query when date is same for some id but time is differ

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one problem while making a query

```
wellid       dated              drillid
1        2000-05-01 11:30:00      123  
1        2000-05-01 11:30:00      124  
1        2000-05-01 11:35:00      123  
1        2000-05-01 11:36:00      124
```

now i want to make a query that return one row when drillid is equal to 123, but there are two dated for drillid 123, so i want only those dated row whose datetime is maximum as compared to other whose drillid is 123 or 124.

suppose i run query for drillid 123 then it must return me

```
wellid       dated              drillid
1        2000-05-01 11:35:00      123
```

but not return me

```
wellid       dated              drillid
1        2000-05-01 11:30:00      123
```

Comment: So, you want only the latest record for any given `drillid`, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT wellid, MAX(dated), drillid
FROM (table name)
WHERE drillid = 123
GROUP BY drillid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE drillid = 123
ORDER BY dated DESC
LIMIT 1;
```